# Generate a Random Flow Network

Tags: algorithm, matlab, graph

I am trying to create a flow network for a given graph so that it can be used to test an algorithm.  To provide clarity, I want the flow into each vertex to equal the flow out.  All flow comes from the source and goes to the sink.  Each edge has a maximum capacity and a direction.  I would like to generate a flow through this network that equals the maximum flow (found by the min cut) that never exceeds the capacity for each edge.

Below is a graphical example of what I am given and what I am trying to obtain.  Of course the "Desired Flow Graph" is not a unique example.  I want this generated randomly.

[Given Weighted Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXsol.png)

[Desired Flow Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbL76.png)

I have this graph represented in MatLab with three arrays.  The first array *s* gives the "from" vertex, the second array *t* gives the "to" vertex, and the third array *w1* gives the maximum capacity from *s* to *t*.  I would like to generate a random array such as *w2* that represents the flow.  (Note the letters in the pictures are equivalent to their corresponding numbers in the code where "A" = 1.

```
s =  [1  1  1  2  3  3  4  6  5  6];
t =  [2  3  4  5  5  6  6  5  7  7];
w1 = [10 15 10 8  5  7  6  5  18 15];
w2 = [8  12 6  8  5  7  6  0  13 13];
```

Any help with some sort of algorithm that can perform this task would be greatly appreciated.  I would love a link to an algorithm, pseudocode, direct code, or even just a description of how such an algorithm may be implemented.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `maxflow` function in MATLAB:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.maxflow.html

For the graph you posted, you can construct a directed graph with these commands:

```
s =  [1  1  1  2  3  3  4  6  5  6];
t =  [2  3  4  5  5  6  6  5  7  7];
w1 = [10 15 10 8  5  7  6  5  18 15];
g = digraph(s,t,w1);
```

Then you can use `maxflow` to calculate the flow values between node 1 and node 7  and return them in a new directed graph `gf`:

```
[mf,gf] = maxflow(g,1,7);
```

The `w2` vector you refer to now just includes the edge weights of the `gf` graph, so you can extract it like this:

```
w2 = gf.Edges.Weight
```

Comment: This does exactly what I was looking for, but I noticed it does not show the value for zero.  For example, the edge from 6 to 5 which has w1=5 was assigned an edge-weight of zero.  This did not show up at all in w2.  That made the size of w2 one less than the size of w1.  Do you know if there is a way around this issue?